# Zend_Filter_Input and validating plain HTML forms

Tags: zend-framework, webforms, validation

ZF 1.11.2 here.

I have something like this in my controller:
`$validators = array(
            'username' => array('Alnum', array('stringLength', false, array('min' => 3, 'max' => 100))),

            'password' => array('Alnum', array('stringLength', false, array('min' => 3, 'max' => 100)))
        );

$input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $_POST);`

My problem is that, no matter how I submit the values, I always get: `'somevalue' is more than 1 characters long`. I couldn't find some article on ZF so I can pull this off (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there shouldn't be `false` parameter for stringLength. Your `$validators` array should be as follows:

```
 $validators = array(
            'username' => array('Alnum', array('stringLength', array('min' => 3, 'max' => 100))),
            'password' => array('Alnum', array('stringLength', array('min' => 3, 'max' => 100)))
        );
```

Comment: Spot on, Marcin! Thanks. I followed the `addValidator('stringLength', false, array(1,100))` syntax.

Comment: For some reason I was using the very same syntax as nevvermind, which I copy pasted from somewhere. Thanks for the clarification :)